# Get hyperlink when looping trough cells

Tags: excel, vba, email, hyperlink, outlook

I have a column with dates and other columns containing some information. one of the other columns is a column with hyperlinks. When the date is reached I want to get the hyperlink and add it to a string, the hyperlink is a link to another excel file. I want to send all this information via mail, and the hyperlink should be clickable and open the excel file.

I got everything working fine except for the hyperlink. 
Now I got 2 questions:

- Is this even possible? If yes, how?
- Can I only open the link on the computer, or is it accessible on my phone too? (phone only has the outlook app, no excel files)

This is what I have so far.

```
Dim nr As Integer
Dim nrString As String
Dim device As String
Dim link As Hyperlink
Dim subj As String
Dim msg As String

Sub Maillijst_verlopen_PO()

    Sheets("PO").Select
    For Each Cell In Range("o2", Range("o2").End(xlDown))
        If Cell.Value < Date And Cell.Value <> "" And Cell.Offset(0, 2) = "actief" Then
            nr = Cell.Offset(, -14).Value
            nrString = CStr(nr)
            device = Cell.Offset(0, -9).Value

            link= "<A href=" & Cell.Offset(0, -6).Value & ">test link</A>"

            subj = "nr " + nrString + ": " + device '+ " " + link
            msg = msg + vbCrLf + subj
        End If
    Next

    msg = "De volgende zaken hebben onderhoud nodig: " + vbCrLf + msg
    Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    msg = ""

End Sub


Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()

    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object

    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With xOutMail
    .To = "....@h....."
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "PO verlopen"
    .Body = msg
    .Send
    End With

    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: In which cell do you want to add hyperlink ? Should it be in `Cell.Offset(0, -6)` ?

Comment: The hyperlink is located in cell.offset(0,-6) I want to get it out of there and add it into a string.

Comment: What if you try `hyperlink = "<A href=""" & Cell.Offset(0, -6).Value & """>test link</A>"`

Comment: Doesnt work. it tells me hyperlink = Nothing

Comment: @Martijn ---- Did you want to call your HyperLink variable `link`? `Nothing` can be the value of an Object Reference Variable when it is assigned to Nothing... An unassigned String would read as `""` which is same as `vbNullString`. If you want to load a string into a variable, then it shoud be declared as `String` I think your declaration line shouldn't be `Dim link As Hyperlink` it should be `Dim hyperlink As String`, purely based on how you are trying to use it...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `Dim link As Hyperlink` to `Dim hyperlink As String` and then you'll have your HyperLink saved into your `hyperlink` variable as a String.

And then of course you can carry on concatenating it with the rest and have it in `subj` when the Commenting is undone...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I originally called it link instead of hyperlink to make it more understandable, but I made it more confusing by doing this and forgetting to rename the variable. Your method does add the text that is in the cell to my string, but it ends up being just a string, not a clickable hyperlink.

Comment: You were asking in your Question why it is not assigning HyperLink to a String Variable?

Comment: Yes, my problem was that I couldn't add the hyperlink to a string. When I change the bodyformat in the mail to HTML it shows me a link. So your method works, thanks alot

Comment: @Martijn --- So sounds like, since you found out that `.HTMLBody` instead of `.Body` fixes the other problem?

Comment: @Martijn --- Well done. Dorian's suggestion to use HTML HyperLink Tag and you changing it to .HTMLBody were actually the most important things...